# Why does driving a screw in spurts work better?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, material-science

When you drive screws into wood with a driver or drill, it is often the case that mid-way through the process the screw will suddenly bind and eject your bit (assuming it's not a Robertson or Torx).

My father-in-law showed me that if you simply drive in little spurts, it will go all the way in without binding.

Now generally, the CoF is *higher* for static than dynamic, so it would seem this is not simply frictional.

Anyone know for SURE why that is? I can make any number of speculations (heat related almost certainly) but I'd like more than a guess.

Comment: A good power driver and a steady hand work wonders without going in spurts.

Comment: That is why I only use torx bits and an impact driver now

Answer (score 5):

The wood you are driving the screw into has a relaxation time of order ~ 1 second during which the cellulose fibers and the lignin resin deform slightly to relieve the pent-up stresses they experience when the screw is initially being driven in. This slightly relieves the clamping force that the wood exerts on the screw, and it becomes slightly easier to drive further- until the screw gets clamped again.

I have found that dense and stiff wood (oak is the perfect example) doesn't relax like this, and the instant the screw driver tip jumps out of the screw you have to back the screw all the way out and either rub a bit of bar soap on the threads and drive it in again or drill out the pilot hole one step bigger.

Comment: That is fascinating!

Answer (score 2):

I partly disagree with Niels' answer because the phenomenon you describe can occur in materials with widely ranging relaxation times.

I think, as the comments suggest, that an equally important phenomenon is the ability of the user to react to changes in the resisting force. Your screwdriver will "jump" if there's a sudden change in the resistance (or if you drift off-vertical...) .  By applying very short bursts, you avoid having to react to such changes in "real time."

Answer (score -4):

When the screw is moving the friction force is smaller than when it is at rest. This answers the question in the title.

When the screw is driven in, it and the wood around it heat up, which increases the friction. The pressure on the screw also increases. The three effects results in the screw suddenly blocking. After a second the heat dissipates, the wood may relax a little, as argued elsewhere, and can be driven in further with increased force. Predrilling will mitigate this.

Comment: OP mentions this in the problem.  It is part of the issue, and doesn't address why stopping and starting would be better if friction force is smaller when moving.

Comment: Indeed, @JMac, I only answered the question in the title. I tend to do this but extended my answer to cover the other questions in the post.

Comment: If you only answer the title, can I choose to vote on your answer based only on the first sentence of it? There is a reason posts aren't just question titles here.

Comment: @my2cts I still don't understand _how_ that would answer the question in the title.  As OP reasons, static friction being greater than dynamic friction is a good reason _not_ to stop, since each time you stop you need to overcome greater friction than if you kept going (all other factors equal).

Comment: @BIoPhysicist The standard here is to ask 1 question per post. So if you ask a question in the title, you used it up. There is no such rule for the number of sentences in a comment.

Comment: You are misunderstanding things here... The point is that you can't just read the title of the question and answer it without reading the body, as the body has more details about the question. I am not talking about asking one question in the title and a different question in the body, nor did I say anything at all about sentence limits in comments

Comment: @BioPhysicist There are more questions in the body, not more details about the same question. The misunderstanding is all yours. Anyway my answer cover the whole OP now.

Comment: The title says "*Why does driving a screw in spurts work better?*". The only question in the body is "*Anyone know for SURE why that is?*", which is talking about the exact scenario asked about in the title. The only point I was trying to make here is that you shouldn't only read the title and then post an answer. As pointed out by @JMac, you completely missed the point of the question by doing so. In any case, I think this conversation is done.